# unable to getting value of input using js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
function addition(){

     var count = 2;
     for(var i = 0 ; i <=count ; i++ ){
           var val = document.getElementById('num');
           alert(val.value);
     }

}
<input type="text" id="num" name="name[]">
<input type="text" id="num" name="name[]">
<input type="submit" id="num"  onclick="addition">
```

I Want to get values of input with the help of single id or name please help me how to get it..

Comment: Your question's title and code are not in sync.

Comment: It's not a good solution to use same id , Id should be unique

Comment: Ur count and i are same 0 is not less than 0 as i know

Comment: @StupidKid It’s `<=`, not `<`.

Comment: Just use `class` instead of `id` and then `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementById`

Comment: Oh i am blind i was sure it was <

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems,

- `onclick` of *submit button* is not invoking `addition`.

i.e. add `()` after `addition`

```
<input type="submit" id="num" onclick="addition()">
```

- Loop's condition is invalid, it will ensure that there is never an iteration `for(var i = 0 ; i <=count ; i++ ){` since your `count` is 0.

Increase the count to 2

```
 var count = 2;
```

- `document.getElementById` will only return one element **since Ids are supposed to be unique**.

**Use `data-id` (*or class or any other `data-` attribute*) instead and use `querySelectorAll` to query those elements**

**Demo**

```js
function addition() {
  var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[data-id='num']");
  for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
    var val = allInputs[i];
    console.log(val.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" data-id="num" name="name[]" value="1">
<input type="text" data-id="num" name="name[]" value="2">
<input type="submit" id="num" onclick="addition()">
```

Answer (score 2):

There can only be one id in a page. Use class, element or attribute selectors instead.

Using a class for the inputs (the button doesn't need a class/id in this case), you can get all elements using [`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), and than you can iterate the collection:

```js
function addition(){
     var val = document.getElementsByClassName('num');
         
     for(var i = 0 ; i < val.length ; i++ ){
           console.log(val[i].value);
     }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="num" name="name[]">
<input type="text" class="num" name="name[]">
<input type="submit" onclick="addition()">
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is your code, then id cannot be duplicated.
you can have multiple fields by same class name but Id should be different.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript one id for one element is a good practice. If you want to get all value then you can use class attribute. So you also can use **document.querySelectorAll** like this -

```
<input type="text" class="num" name="name[]">
<input type="text" class="num" name="name[]">
<input type="submit" onclick="addition()">

function addition(){
     var val = document.querySelectorAll('.num');

     for(var i = 0 ; i < val.length ; i++ ){
           console.log(val[i].value);
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks mate you saved my life <3